# Are the haters un-American or do the haters hate un-American (actions)?

Tags: meaning, grammar, ambiguity

[image: Jeanine Pirro tweet about Trump and North Korean summit]

@JudgeJeanine: "@realDonaldTrump is bringing America back in front of our eyes and it's time for the un-American haters to get on board."

I know what she intended. To invite anyone who disagrees with her  (un-American(s) and haters of America) to join her. However, isn’t there another interpretation?

Broccoli haters aren’t haters who are broccoli. They hate that which is broccoli.

Therefore, un-American haters wouldn’t be haters who are un-American. Rather, they’d hate that which is Un-American; that which is not characteristic of or consistent with American customs, principles, or traditions.

Comment: Yes, real language is often potentially ambiguous, and occasionally actually ambiguous.

Comment: I hate ambiguous stuff like that!

Comment: The haters ( ~nevertrumpers ) are un-American in her opinion.  I do not see, in this context, any other interpretation.

Comment: @lbf No. That would be tantamount to saying that broccoli-haters are broccoli.

Comment: This question raises an even more vexing  question: what is an 'un-broccoli hater'?

Comment: @SvenYargs It's pretty obvious. The fact that you even ask that question calls severely into question your broccoliism. _records IP address for the authorities_

Comment: @Mitch: "Broccolism" sounds like a toxic bacterial infection contracted by consuming badly canned vegetables. Heretofore, the worst I've been accused of is Asparagus syndrome.

Comment: @Sven As a firm believer in the superpower of literalism that ASD gives people, except when it doesn't, I can totally understand your misconception...given your misspelling.

Comment: This could be a poorly phrased way of saying "Let's get the people who don't hate Americans on board with the rest of us who want to see America right in front of our eyes [and hate it]."  I say this as an American.

Comment: @Mitch: This is why I can't have green things.

Answer (score 1):

“Broccoli” is a noun. “Un-American” is an adjective. You can hate a noun, but not an adjective (unless you’re using unusual phrasing to produce some kind of rhetorical effect), so I don’t think “un-American haters” is actually ambiguous in the way that you suggest.

“Broccoli haters” is technically ambiguous, but the ambiguity is resolved is practice by knowing that broccoli cannot hate anything.

Comment: my thoughts too!

Comment: I’m not really sure it would be so unusual to use a (nominalised) adjective here. Most adjectives can be nominalised to mean ‘something/anything which is X’; _un-American_ seems quite happy to. So just as a _happy-hater_ would be someone who hates anything that’s happy, an _un-American–hater_ would be someone who hates anything that’s un-American. It’s not a likely parsing, and I’d say it definitely requires the hyphen to be parseable that way at all, but it is possible to me.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly here, **this could work all ways poetically !**  !?

In essence: "Bother the haters and those that hate haters need to get on-board our cause"

Lets say: **un-american** gets translated to **'racist'**
(and ambiguous whether than means **a person** who behaves with racism o**r the adjective** 'filled with racism')

**GREATER AMBIGUITY - racist haters**  (instead of un-american haters) could **mean BOTH**

- "racist and hateful people"
- "people who hate racists"

**Now does't "get on board" generally mean mean "come join our cause" ?**

If you invite a criminal to "get on board" can't this only mean "come on over to the good side" ?

Like if Nancy Pelosi said about the 15$ minimum wage : "It's time for Republicans to get on-board" ?

**So wouldn't**

- *"it's time for "people who hate racists" to get on-board"*

**and**

- *"it's time for "racist and hateful people" to get on-board"*

**BOTH be messages that the tweeter would support ?**

Ambiguous in that it can mean either,  however **perhaps Tweeter wants Both?** ?

**Is Ambiguity that Means both possible outcomes bad ?**

(Should I change this to a separate question?)

Comment: Is "American" a "race"?

Comment: @WS2 no.   un-american however is generally meant to refer to a behavior not befitting an american, not an absence of ties to the country or culture.  While it is a metaphorical sort of idiom without any precise meaning, generally while a cheeseburger might be called 'american food'  the idiom is less used for describing 'pate' ' or 'foi gras'  -  'non-american'  foods more than 'un-american' foods? Some might use other traits/noun combinations like "imperialist" or "elitist" - and American is not an 'imperial' or an "elite" etc.

Comment: @WS2 BTW I think it was clear I was having fun with the contemplation rather than trying to make any claim of "answer" - I like the idea of something ambiguous meaning both A & B  but I do think it is better to say that a person means both A & B if that is the case.  I suppose I could put a "wink" ;) in the answer somewhere